# Environment variable not set in profile.d script

Tags: environment-variables, .profile

I created a script
`/etc/profile.d/mkl_restriction.sh` which contains the following line:

`export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`

When I log in (via ssh if that matters), the variable is not set, but if I run `source /etc/profile.d/mkl_restriction.sh`, it becomes properly set. What is going on?

Comment: Is it also set if you source `/etc/profile`? because that by default contains the code that sources `.sh` files in `/etc/profile.d/`

Comment: Maybe the permissions of `/etc/profile.d/mkl_restriction.sh` are set wrong and not owned by root?  I just did a test and it worked for me.  `-rw-r--r--   1 root root    25 Jan 31 18:54 mkl_restriction.sh`

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it turns out I was using `zsh`, which explains why `/etc/profile` was not sourced.